# simplified Linear programming model with time constraints

Tags: linear-programming, applications

Based on my [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444992/solving-linear-programming-with-time-constraints), here is a simpler hypothetical exercise that isolates that time constraint issue all 
together:

- A farmer has 1000 ha forest that is already at a mature age assumed to be 40
- currently 200 ha are of wood type A and the rest are of wood type B

Wood types A and B have the following m3 per ha

```
Age    yield_A    yield_B
25     10         10
30     20         20
35     31         49
40     40         63
45     50         70
```

Wood types regenerate at the following rate (m3/ha):

```
Age   regen_a    regen_b
5     3          4
10    11         19
15    24         35
20    35         48
25    50         69
30    75         86
35    101        121
```

wood type A sells for \$100/ha while type B sells for \$75/ha. Prices will increase 3% per period

**Optimization:**

Maximize the revenue of the farm over a 40 year period as well as period over period assuming 5 year periods and at that after 40 years , 70% of the forest is still planted.

**Attempted solution:**

*Optimization functions:*

```
max_revenue_period_n = ($_a * vol_a + $_b * vol_b) for period n
max_revenue_overall = ($_a * vol_a + $_b * vol_b)
```

*Constraints:*

```
at age 40: vol_a_40 + vol_b_40 >= 0.6 (vol_a_0 + vol_a_40)
```

**Question:**

How can I incorporate the time aspect of yields, regeneration, and optimizing over multiple periods into the problem?